# Insert data to elasticsearch with jQuery and get the id of the last inserted document

Tags: jquery, elasticsearch

With the following code I insert data to my elasticsearch index:

```
var personendaten = { 
   "vorname": $.trim( $( '#vorname' ).val() ),
   "nachname": $.trim( $( '#nachname' ).val() )
};

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'http://localhost:9200/castingdb/personen',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: JSON.stringify( personendaten ),
   success: function( pid ){
      window.location = '?seite=personen&sub=profil&id='+pid;
   }
});
```

In my success function I need a return value from elasticsearch which gives me the id of the inserted document.
With PHP and MySQL there is the last_insert_id function, is there something similar I can use with jQuery and elasticsearch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe once you insert the record you are getting back json response of this form:

> {"ok":true,"_index":"you index name","_type":"you type name","_id":"id of inserted document","_version":1}

so in your case `pid._id` is what you are looking for